# iBeacon - Maximum limit to monitor regions

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, geofencing

Is there any limit to number of iBeacon regions that a device can monitor?
Is there any such limit of 20 region that an application can monitor.

Please suggest.

Comment: There are 2 questions asked, and the first one - global limit per device is not addressed by the suggested answer. Meanwhile, there are really interesting findings, which might explain a lot of discrepancies frequently mentioned on SO. The referenced article suggests that global limit is ~30 hardware regions featuring almost instant fence triggering, with everything else being software or "best efforts" regions susceptible to significantly delayed or even missing notifications: http://bit.ly/1IhCnIE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer of @dwsolberg

You can set a maximum of 20 regions to monitor. (Found in documentation for the `startMonitoringForRegion:` method.) Region limits mostly come into play if your app is in the background. The OS will alert your app when you enter or leave a region that you're monitoring (give or take a few minutes). The OS will even launch your app just to let it know what happened (although only for a short time).

The other method is ranging, which is to find all the beacons within the Bluetooth range of the device (typically around 100 feet give or take). If your beacons are spread out over 100 miles, then you probably won't run into any practical limit here.

For more details on Region Monitoring you can refer Apple's documentation on [Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)

Comment: Don't copy other people's answers. If the question is answered elsewhere, add a link to it and / or flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @jrturton: Ok but I have added link to apple's documentation also which is relevant to this & was not in that answer